# As a new Python (or any language) programmer I'm having trouble with my program loop.

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write a multiplication game for my son.  When it runs it will show an index card with a two random numbers multiplied together.

When you click on the card it will show the answer on the "back" of the index card.

```
import pygame, sys, random

pygame.init()

black = (0,0,0)

# screen
(width, height) = (480, 320)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Math Flashcards")

#background color
background_color = ((black))
screen.fill(background_color)
print(background_color)

#Index Card Position (Center)
card_front = pygame.image.load('img/indexcard.png')
card_back = pygame.image.load('img/indexcard.png')
card_w = card_front.get_width()
card_h = card_front.get_height()
card_pos = (((width - card_w) / 2), (height - card_h) / 2)
print('Width =',card_w, "Height =",card_h)
print('Card Position' ,card_pos)

#Create Random Numbers 0-9
num_1 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
num_2 = str(random.randint(0, 9))
print('num_1 =',num_1)
print('num_2 =',num_2)

# calculate the answer and render font
ans = int(num_1)*int(num_2)
print('the answer is ',ans)

#Create font
blue = (0,0,255)
font_size = 75
myfont = pygame.font.SysFont("Courier", font_size)

# apply it to text on a label
l1 = myfont.render(num_1, 1, blue)
lX = myfont.render("x", 1, blue)
l2 = myfont.render(num_2, 1, blue)
lans = myfont.render(str(ans), 1, blue)

# put the label object on the screen at position
l1_pos = (((width/2)-(font_size *1)),(height/2)-(font_size/2))
print(l1_pos)
lX_pos = (((width/2)-(font_size *.38)),(height/2)-(font_size/2))
print(lX_pos)
l2_pos = (((width/2)-(font_size *-.20)),(height/2)-(font_size/2))
print(l2_pos)
lans_pos =(((width/2)-(font_size/2)),(height/2)-(font_size/2))
print(lans_pos)

screen.blit(card_front, card_pos)
screen.blit(l1, (l1_pos))
screen.blit(lX, (lX_pos))
screen.blit(l2, (l2_pos))

running = True
while running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            screen.blit(card_back, card_pos)
            screen.blit(lans, (lans_pos))
            pygame.display.flip()

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()
```

This will only run once.  I'd like for it to reset to a new multiplication problem when I click the index card a second time.  this is where I need some help.

I just started programming in Python this week.  I'm surprised I got this far.  Any and all help is very much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: You need to add more logging. Try adding some `print` statements to various places (i.e. places where `running` can be set to `False` or where your app may quit). It seems like app is ended prematurely because of this.

Comment: I don't exactly remember how Python would behave, but in most languages, your second `elif` will never execute cause your first `elif` always takes precedence.

**EDIT:** I just tested it, your first case will indeed *always* take precedence.

Answer (score 0):

As Edward L. points out in the comments, your second elif will never execute. Every time the program reaches the first elif and it evaluates to True, it will run that and skip over the second elif. Try something like this:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    count = 0
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and count == 0:
        screen.blit(card_back, card_pos)
        screen.blit(lans, (lans_pos))
        pygame.display.flip()
        count = 1

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN and count == 1:
        running = False
```